# How can I create different list for each text file?

Tags: c, list

I have written so far the program below, but the point is that this one creates a list for all the packets, that succeed to enter the list. I want to have 10 lists instead of 1 and that is because I have 10 text files to open. I think that using the same insert function 10 times, will create the same list, so do I have to create 10 head pointers, so when text file 1 opens, the packets from it will enter the list 1 and etc.?  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
struct Packet
{
  int rollnumber;
  int src;
  int dest;
  double gentime;
  struct Packet *next;
 }* head;

void insert(int rollnumber, int src, int dest, double gentime)
{
 struct Packet * packet = (struct Packet *) malloc(sizeof(struct Packet));

  packet->rollnumber = rollnumber;
  packet->src=src;
  packet->dest=dest;
  packet->gentime = gentime;
  packet->next = NULL;

  if(head==NULL){
    // if head is NULL
    // set packet as the new head
    head = packet;
  }
  else{
    // if list is not empty
    // insert packet in beginning of head
    packet->next = head;
    head = packet;
   }

}

void display()
{
struct Packet * temp = head;
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    printf("Roll Number: %d\n",temp->rollnumber);
    printf("src: %d\n", temp->src);
    printf("dest: %d\n", temp->dest);
    printf("gentime: %0.1f\n\n", temp->gentime);
    //printf("offtime: %0.1f\n\n", temp->offtime);
    temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH] = {0};

int src,dest;
int rollnumber;
double gentime;

int i=1;

static unsigned long pos[] = {0};

FILE *file;
char filename_format[] = "fptg_%d.txt";

double Time=12.0; 
int insertedpackets[1000]; 


struct node * head = NULL;




for (Time=12.0; Time<60.0; Time=Time+12.0){
        
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
        
        char to_open[32];
        snprintf(to_open,32, "fptg_%d.txt", i);
        printf("\n\nFPTG_%d.txt\n", i);
        
        if ((file = fopen(to_open, "r")) == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }else{
                fseek(file , pos[i], SEEK_CUR);
                fgets(line, sizeof(line), file);
                sscanf(line,"%d %d %d %lf",&rollnumber, &src, &dest, &gentime);
                printf("%s", line);
                printf("Return value=%d\n",sscanf(line, " %d %d %d %lf", &rollnumber, &src, &dest, &gentime));
                printf("gentime=%.1f\n", gentime);
                pos[i] = ftell(file);
            if (gentime<Time){
               
                printf("ok\n");
                insert(rollnumber,src,dest,gentime); 
                printf("Time=%0.1f\n", Time);
                
            }
           fclose(file); 
        }  
    }
 }
 printf("\n\nTHE LIST:\n");
 display();
}
```

Comment: `char filename[sizeof(filename_format) + 4];` doesn't make sense, this variable is not used anyway. Your code could be reproducible, but it's not minimum.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani just did some edit in order to be minimum, sorry for the trouble before

Comment: After calling `fopen`, call `fclose` when you no longer need the file pointer. It looks like this is trying to `fopen` the same file, the second time it will fail and it doesn't print an error.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani added that too, but what about the different lists I need to create? Is this possible?